# will installing Ubuntu convert my hard disk to a dynamic disk?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I have 3 partitions in windows 8, and I want to install Ubuntu ,and I know Ubuntu will need at least 2 partitions,so in total it will be 5 partitions in the hard disk, so will this convert my hard disk to a to dynamic disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, dynamic disks are a Windows thing that is not supported in Ubuntu.  If you are using the msdos partition table ( recent UEFI machines with Windows 8 should be using GPT ), then the installer will create a 4th partition called extended partition, and place the other logical partitions inside it.